# convert Iteratee to Result

Tags: scala, playframework

I am writing test-cases for my play application controller, and I am having trouble getting the action result.

```
val jsonresult = UserController.importOPML()( 
   FakeRequest(POST, "/user/import-opml",FakeHeaders(),data)
   .withCookies(cookie) 
)
```

this would work only when the Action is specified `parse.multipartFormData`, if it is changed to `parse.json`

> **type mismatch; found : play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee[Array[Byte],play.api.mvc.SimpleResult] required: 
>        scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.SimpleResult]**

I don't know why , so I changed to

```
val Some(jsonresult ) = route( request )
```

this time the compilation can pass, but my Authentication stub cannot pass anymore. what is causing that weird error ? and if work with route, why the cookie didn't work.

Comment: put result in future block

Comment: Can you post more of your code, for example one simplified test case. Btw. you should be able to get your stuff working by calling `contentAsString(jsonresult)` or `contentAsJson(jsonresult)` (make sure you have `import play.api.test.Helpers._` to use those).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem arises because `play.api.mvc.Action[A]` contains these two apply methods:

```
// What you're hoping for
def apply(request: Request[A]): Future[Result]

// What actually gets called
def apply(rh: RequestHeader): Iteratee[Array[Byte], Result]
```

`Request[A] extends RequestHeader`, so the `A` in this case makes all the difference. If it doesn't match the action, you'll call the wrong method.

If your action is a `Action[AnyContent]`, then you must pass a `Request[AnyContent]` - `Request[AnyContentAsJson]` will work, but `FakeRequest[JsValue]` won't, because only the former is a `Request[AnyContent]`.

When you use `ActionBuilder` with a `BodyParser[A]`, you create an `Action[A]`. As a result, you'll need a `Request[A]` to test, which means that the type of `data` in your question is critically important.

- `parse.json` returns a `BodyParser[JsValue]`, so `data` must be a `JsValue`
- `parse.multipartFormData` returns a `BodyParser[MultipartFormData[TemporaryFile]]`, so `data` must be multi-part form data.

*(Note: It's been a while since you asked this question, so I'm answering it using Play 2.3, rather than the 2.2 that you were using when it was asked.)*

Comment: I worked around using some other method. your answer sounds reasonable. what I am complaining is the API, which is not consistent at all.

Comment: I'm getting similar problems for my secured actions, is there a similar solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303705/secured-trait-causing-spec2-unit-test-compilation-errors

Comment: This was it in my case. Constructing the `FakeRequest` via the case class constructor instead of the companion object's `apply` function fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

tjdett's answer explains the issue in detail.

For a quick solution that may work in your instance simply `run` the iteratee result payload.

```
val jsonresult = UserController.importOPML()( 
   FakeRequest(POST, "/user/import-opml",FakeHeaders(),data)
   .withCookies(cookie) 
).run
```