# Secured trait causing spec2 unit test compilation errors

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I've implemented authorization for my Play Framework (version 2.3.5) application as per the [official security documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.8/ScalaSecurity#Authorization):

```
trait Secured {

  def username(request: RequestHeader) = request.session.get(Security.username)

  def onUnauthorized(request: RequestHeader) = Results.Redirect(routes.Login.index)

  def withAuth(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = {
    Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
      Action(request => f(user)(request))
    }
  }

}
```

However, when I decorate my controller actions with the `withAuth` function like so:

```
def export = withAuth { username => implicit request =>
  val csv = csv()
  Ok(csv)
    .as("text/csv")
    .withHeaders(
      CONTENT_DISPOSITION -> ("attachment; filename=export.csv"),
      CONTENT_LENGTH -> csv.length.toString
    )
}
```

I get compilation errors in my controller specs2 unit tests:

```
"export data as CSV" in {
  val controller = new controllers.DataController
  val result = controller.export().apply(FakeRequest())
  headers(result) must havePair("Content-Disposition" -> ("attachment; filename=export.csv"))
}
```

The call to the `headers` test helper function fails with the following compiler error message:

> type mismatch;  found   : play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee[Array[Byte],play.api.mvc.Result]  required: scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]

Am I doing something wrong? I've tried some of the [remedies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23311787/convert-iteratee-to-result) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452491/unable-to-test-controller-using-action-async) by other Stackoverflow users but they all seem to rely on setting the body type, but my actions do not have a body type.

It looks as though the call to `withAuth` obscures some of the types of the Action being wrapped so maybe there is a more type-safe way of expressing the `Secured` trait?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
val result = controller.export().apply(FakeRequest())
```

into this:

```
val result = controller.export().apply(FakeRequest()).run
```

And then it should work.